# Angular 5/6 search data returned from Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, html, typescript

I have api which return movies data from external api, I have implemented a search function  in my api ,  here is what i have so far:

component.ts:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
   movies: any;
   searchRes: any;
   searchStr: any;
 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http, private location: Location, private moviesService: MoviesService) {
      this.movies = [];
  }
  searchMovies() {
    this.moviesService.searchMovies(this.searchStr).then(res => {
        this.searchRes = res.results;
    });
 }
}
```

service.ts:

```
export class MoviesService {
  searchStr: string;
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/movies';
  constructor(private http: Http, private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }
  searchMovies(searchStr: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(this.handleData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
}

  private handleData(res: any) {
    const body = res.json();
    console.log(body); // for development purposes only
    return body.result || body || { };
}
 private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
     console.error('An error occurred', error); // for development purposes only
     return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }
}
 }
```

compo.html

```
<form (submit)="searchMovies()">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" name="searchStr">
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search your Favourite Movies</button>  
        </form>

 <div *ngFor="let movie of searchRes;let i=index" class="col-md-2">
            <div *ngIf="i < 18">
            <img *ngIf="movie.poster_path" class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
            <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
            <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when I run the app everything works fine and when I trie to search eg Avengers, it displays all movies not just movies which goea by the name avengers, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem above is even though you are passing **`searchStr`** as a parameter to the method, you are not actually passing to the **`api`**,

```
searchMovies(searchStr: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl) //pass  **`searchStr`** here
               .toPromise()
               .then(this.handleData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: `  searchMovies(searchStr: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + searchStr)
               .toPromise()
               .then(this.handleData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
`

Comment: this does not display anything in  my page just error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: dude! you need to check the url of your api and match the request accordingly, i have mentioned whats the issue

Comment: how does your api look like?

Comment: I added something like this :   `queryUrl = '?search=';` and  `searchMovies(searchStr: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + this.queryUrl + searchStr)
               .toPromise()
               .then(this.handleData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
}` i still get all movies, am stuck :( sorry for taking your time bro

Comment: ` app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
  request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?&sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=2931998c3a80d7806199320f76d65298', function (error, response, body) {
   console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
   console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
   res.send(body)
    });
 });`